# C# console re run application at a specific condition

Tags: c#, console, runtime

I am creating a C# console application of showroom.
I want something like that:

```
{
customer comes and places an order. 
when order completse then I want the main page back. 
where customer can re order or re use this application.
}
```

Actually I want to re run application during runtime.
Is there any specific function or syntax in C#?

Comment: Why don't you put your main functionality in a loop?

Comment: Why cant you place your customer come and order code/scenario inside a do while loop,so that at run time you can take orders and customers can exit from the order place

Comment: i know but i am looking for any function if there is any ??
so that is why i posted !

Comment: Something like queue data structure you need to implement .

Comment: You need to save the results in a database.  It can be a real database or a file (which is technically a database).  You have to specify the settings that you need saved so they can be restored.  The format of the saved data/configuration is up to you.

Comment: "costumer" deals with clothes

Answer (score 1):

I dont know any function that reruns your program. But I also think that its not the best idea to just rerun the program if you want to get back to the programs starting point. 
Here is a sample implementation of the loop:

```
class Program
{

    private bool _running = true;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        while (program._running)
        {
            PlaceOrders();
            ...
            if (exitCondition)
            {
                program._running = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should store all your orders in a database or something similar. At the start of the application you can then load all the orders and give the user the possibility of changing orders, ...